# How to check SV class property existance

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I want to check if my class parent class has such property. And if yes, than access to it.

```
if ( $cast(this.get_parent(), agent_inst) && agent_inst != "NULL" )
        if (agent_inst.vitf != "NULL")
            vitf = agent_inst.vitf;
```

Now if agent_inst does not have vitf property, the simulator will give an error.
So how I can check if agent_inst has the vitf property?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to $cast backwards; the first argument is the target variable, the second is source. The way $cast works, you should have declared `agent_inst` with a class type that has a `vitf` property. The $cast only succeeds at run-time if the source object is type compatible with the target. Your code will not compile unless `agent_inst.vitf` exists.

Comment: Yes right, thanks for the answer
Just I wanted to write more general code, when my agent_inst may not even have vitf object. In such case $cast does not help

Comment: If you want more generic code, define an agent base class that has a vitf property and has anything else a generic agent should have.